# Is a LXC environment a mandatory requirement for operating mesos/sphere

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I plan to make a proposal for a proof of concept(POC) project employing mesos/sphere targeting the  OS IBM AIX. At least for the mesos/sphere slaves.

*Short remark: with the term mesos/sphere i subsume both projects, mesos and mesossphere, to be the "framework" projects of that POC.*

I have read about the isolation feature and that it uses cgroups and hence a LXC environment. Referencing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC, IBM AIX does use an alternative approach and does NOT implement cgroups.

So i can not expect that all features of mesos/sphere will work on IBM AIX. But on the other side i can not pre-evalute from docs and research  under which if-s which features might work or are to be configured respectively.

So, targeting IBM AIX as the OS prospectively running mesos/sphere, is/can  mesos/sphere ...

- designed to work ?
- be expected respective to which features not to work ?
- be pin pointed to configuration documentation/help that is not expected to work ?
- expected to be supported by the community?
- under anyone's productive usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for trying mesos under AIX!
There is no official support for AIX,so unfortunately also no documentation what might be potential problems.

Did you try building mesos (make && make check) on AIX? That should give a good indicator for potential problems.

To your LXC questions: Mesos supports a number of different ways to isolate processes: See for example [mesos-containerizer](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-containerizer/),[docker containerizer](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/) or [external containerizer](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/external-containerizer/).
So even without cgroups Mesos will still work, it will just not be able to isolate tasks with cgroups.
For example I can at least test Mesos fine on my Mac Book (which does not offer cgroups).

Hope this helped,
Joerg